# How to current instance of presented view Controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am using the following code to Present the view controller,

```
      ViewController *ViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
      ViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;            
      UINavigationController *navLayersViewController = [UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:ViewController];
[self presentViewController:navLayersViewController
                       animated:YES
                     completion:^{

                     }];
```

I want to get the current instance of this preseneted "viewController" in some other class.How can I get it. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

you need to present the navigation controller first.

```
  ViewController *myViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
  myViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;            
  UINavigationController *navLayersViewController = [UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myViewController];
```

If you are presenting this in a view controller class, then do

```
 [self presentViewController: navLayersViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

else get the reference of root controller, then do

```
[rootController presentViewController: navLayersViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need two viewcontrollers to know about each other, you have an architecture problem.

Normally, your VC only handles visuals / UI interactions, like animations, or button touches. These things obviously don't need to go outisde of the VC (VC2 does not care that VC1 has a fade animation, or 3 buttons).

When it comes to displaying data, the data comes from an outside class/service/manager ; people call it many different things.

But the good news is, if that "service" is outside of your controller, you can use it from anywhere.

From VC1, you can do `myService.GetListOfMessages();` (for example), and nothing stops you from doing it from another class, using that very same service. And you can now access your list of messages from VC1, VC2, or anywhere necessary.

Keep in mind that, in general, your VC shouldn't be doing anything not related to visuals. If you're doing webservice calls, business logic or anything like that, it belongs to another class. That way, it's organized (which should be enough just by itself), but also, if your visuals change, or you need the same logic somewhere else, you'll already have the class ready.

That is not a complete example, but if you're comfortable enough in programming you should be just fine implementing this.

Just be careful :

- Do not overuse singletons, or worse, statics.
- Do not forget about single responsibility ( do not shove everything in one class).
- Do not make webservice calls that aren't necessary. If it's data that you're using a lot, just keep it in memory.

With all that in mind, you should be fine, and your controllers will actually handle less work, while still having access to the data they need.